How do I add my UWP app to the share menu in Microsoft Edge?
I've been trying to integrate my Universal Windows Platform (UWP) app into the share menu of Microsoft Edge, but despite adding the necessary configurations to my package.appxmanifest file, it still doesn't appear in the share menu.
Here's what I've added to my package.appxmanifest file:
        <uap:Extension Category="windows.shareTarget">
          <uap:ShareTarget Description="share">
            <uap:SupportedFileTypes>
              <uap:SupportsAnyFileType/>
            </uap:SupportedFileTypes>
            <uap:DataFormat>Web link</uap:DataFormat>
            <uap:DataFormat>Text</uap:DataFormat>
            <uap:DataFormat>Images</uap:DataFormat>
          </uap:ShareTarget>
        </uap:Extension>

I'm still unable to get my app to show up in the Edge share menu. What am I missing here?

When you click more tools->share in edge browser, it shows a share window that built-in the browser. It's not a system window. Could you please take a look at the Windows share options item in the Share with others menu of share window of the Edge? This item will launch the windows built-in share window. Generally, share target apps will show in the that system share window.

this is where I searched for my app, but unfortunately, it's not visible in Edge; it only appears within the Windows interface.

Thank you for your help
I've identified the issue; I needed to include formatting for both Uri and Html.

I'm glad to hear that you've found the reason yourself. Would you like to post your reply as answer?

The issue was that I needed to include formatting for both Uri and Html. After adding them, the problem was resolved:
          <uap:ShareTarget Description="share">
            <uap:SupportedFileTypes>
              <uap:SupportsAnyFileType/>
            </uap:SupportedFileTypes>
            <uap:DataFormat>WebLink</uap:DataFormat>
            <uap:DataFormat>Uri</uap:DataFormat>
            <uap:DataFormat>Text</uap:DataFormat>
            <uap:DataFormat>Images</uap:DataFormat>
            <uap:DataFormat>Html</uap:DataFormat>
          </uap:ShareTarget>

Additionally, I discovered an example repository for creating the app share target:
Windows Universal Samples - Share Target.
